# Offline PWA not behaving as expected on phones. Asks for connectivity despite caching all relevant files

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, offline-browsing

I am trying to make an offline PWA planner targeted to phones and I have *no need at all* for user data or interaction with my home page after installation.

Everything works fine on my PC and Lighthouse gives a clean bill of health, but on my phone (S8) the PWA does not work as expected in Chrome and Firefox when I am offline.
Minimizing the app and tapping the installed icon works in Chrome as long as I am online, but occasionally gives a black screen in Firefox, especially if the app has lost focus for a while.
Going offline causes Chrome to ignore the cached files and complain about lack of connectivity if reloaded, for example after a phone restart or closing all apps.
Firefox just hangs with a white or black screen.

I cache my index.html file and have a suspicion that reinstalling the service worker on reload will flush the cache if offline, but despite extensive searches I haven't been able to find a way around this - or even a mentioning.
I experience the same problem on a  Samsung S5 and on an iPad.

Included below is the script in my html header:

```
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/FuzzyPlan_serviceWorker.js', { scope: '/' }).then(function(registration) {
          console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
        }, function(err) {
          console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
        });
      });
    }
    </script>
```

And my service worker code:

```
let CACHED_URLS = [
  '200px-A_SVG_semicircle_heart_empty.svg.png',
  '200px-A_SVG_semicircle_heart.svg.png',
  '200px-Flag_of_Denmark.png',
  '200px-Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom.png',
  'FuzzyPlan20211002.css',
  'FuzzyPlan20211002.js',
  'apple-touch-icon.png',
  'favicon.ico',
  'favicon.png',
  'icon.svg',
  'index.html',
  'instructions_dk.html',
  'instructions.html',
  'manifest.json',
  'favicons/maskable_192.png',
  'favicons/favicon-512.png'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(FP_CACHE).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll(CACHED_URLS);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  console.log('Fetch request for: ', event.request.url);
  event.respondWith( caches.match(event.request, {ignoreVary: true}).then( // ignoreVary should make the cache match ignore flags and stuff that can make a mathc fail unintentionally
    function(response) {
      return response || fetch(event.request);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log('FuzzyPlan serviceWorker responded with error', error);
    })
  );
})
```

I'd appreciate an explanation of where I have made a rookie mistake :-)

The full project is at https://github.com/HappyDustbunny/FuzzyPlan

Comment: Is it hosted somewhere? My initial guess is service worker gets registered but not activated? Have you checked the CACHED_URLS being present in the cache on successful install? 
Secondly, the `caches.match(event.request, ...)` , what is this returning? As per your explanation it seems to be returning `fetch(event.request)`

Comment: Yeah, it's hosted at fuzzyplan.madshorn.dk/index.html

Comment: Thanks for responding btw :-) The service worker is installed and the cache is filled. I can't remember finding any hitches on PC. It is when using it on the phone problems arise. Firefox is slow when launced from the icon and often gives a black screen. Chrome is quick, but complains if I go offline - which is why I tried to make it a PWA. As I understand the book I used for writing the service worker ```cahces.match(event.request, ...)``` should return stuff from the cache if found, but fall back on network if the cache is missing/corrupted.

Comment: I can definitely see it working on my mobile device. Chrome nudged me to install the PWA, I did that, went offline, and the assets loaded fine. Is it isolated to a specific chrome version / phone?

Comment: I really apreciate your effort :-)  It may be specific to my phone. I just failed to reproduce the bug on my spare S5 (S4?). Firefox is slow, but both Chrome and Firefox seems to work on this phone. It may be some sort of caching issue with the service worker being slow to update. I'll try to reset both browsers on my phone by deleting all data and then reinstall the PWA. And find other phones to experiment on. I'll close or update this question in a couple of days. Thanks for now :-)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The original question is answered: the PWA part is working just fine.**

A kind person tried the PWA on his phone and found no problem, which prompted me to test more thoroughly on phones other than my own, and it seems that the PWA part is working as it should.

What tricked me was having tested older versions on other phones that did not work.

The PWA part of latest update *do* work, but it has another – yet unidentified – glitch.

This glitch is not readily reproducible, but after encountering a white screen in Chrome, I connected the phone to the computer via USB and used Chrome DevTools (by typing chrome://inspect/#devices in the address line) to pick apart the innards of the app.
Everything was there (service worker, manifest, cache, DOM, …) and I could interact with the javascript in the console, but the screen was white. Both on the phone and in DevTools. (Suggestions welcome!!!)
It even logged swipe events to the console, an earler debugging effort I have forgotten to remove.

I suspect the culprit is me trying to take over navigation via the back-button at the bottom at every phone (the triangle) and messing it up somehow.
I’ll have to test this more on my own and open a new question if I get stuck.